# Windows server 2016 Configuration Manager Client (5.00.8458.1000) fail

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2016

I have two fresh installs of Windows server 2016

Everytime I try to run  Configuration Manager Client (5.00.8458.1000) i get an error

Configuration Manager Client (5.00.8458.1000) - Error 0x80070643

I have disabled UAC

Ran C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install\ccmsetup.exe as administrator and from the local administrator account

Most everything I find online refers to Server 2012 r2, trying as many as I can find makes no difference.

My question, is Configuration Manager Client update important?

It is the only update I see when running windows update so i am concerned there are more updates that are dependent on it.

Yes PC Is joined to domain

No i am not running SCCM anywhere.

On each server:

```
[X] File and Storage Services                           FileAndStorage-Services        Installed
    [X] File and iSCSI Services                         File-Services                  Installed
        [X] File Server                                 FS-FileServer                  Installed
    [X] Storage Services                                Storage-Services               Installed
[X] Hyper-V                                             Hyper-V                        Installed
[X] .NET Framework 4.6 Features                         NET-Framework-45-Fea...        Installed
    [X] .NET Framework 4.6                              NET-Framework-45-Core          Installed
    [X] WCF Services                                    NET-WCF-Services45             Installed
        [X] TCP Port Sharing                            NET-WCF-TCP-PortShar...        Installed
[X] Failover Clustering                                 Failover-Clustering            Installed
[X] Multipath I/O                                       Multipath-IO                   Installed
[X] Remote Server Administration Tools                  RSAT                           Installed
    [X] Feature Administration Tools                    RSAT-Feature-Tools             Installed
        [X] Failover Clustering Tools                   RSAT-Clustering                Installed
            [X] Failover Cluster Management Tools       RSAT-Clustering-Mgmt           Installed
            [X] Failover Cluster Module for Windows ... RSAT-Clustering-Powe...        Installed
    [X] Role Administration Tools                       RSAT-Role-Tools                Installed
        [X] Hyper-V Management Tools                    RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools             Installed
            [X] Hyper-V GUI Management Tools            Hyper-V-Tools                  Installed
            [X] Hyper-V Module for Windows PowerShell   Hyper-V-PowerShell             Installed
[X] SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support                   FS-SMB1                        Installed
[X] Windows Defender Features                           Windows-Defender-Fea...        Installed
    [X] Windows Defender                                Windows-Defender               Installed
    [X] GUI for Windows Defender                        Windows-Defender-Gui           Installed
[X] Windows PowerShell                                  PowerShellRoot                 Installed
    [X] Windows PowerShell 5.1                          PowerShell                     Installed
    [X] Windows PowerShell ISE                          PowerShell-ISE                 Installed
[X] WoW64 Support                                       WoW64-Support                  Installed
```

C:\Windows\ccmsetup\Logs\ccmsetup.log

```
<![LOG[==========[ ccmsetup started in process 2544 ]==========]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.078+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:9498">
<![LOG[Updated security on object C:\Windows\ccmsetup\cache\.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.078+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:9342">
<![LOG[Launch from folder C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install\]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.078+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:627">
<![LOG[CcmSetup version: 5.0.8458.1007]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.078+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:633">
<![LOG[Folder 'Microsoft\Microsoft\Configuration Manager' not found. Task does not exist.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.078+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="wintask.cpp:648">
<![LOG[Folder 'Microsoft\Microsoft\Configuration Manager' not found. Task does not exist.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.078+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="wintask.cpp:648">
<![LOG[[ACD-FO3] Running on 'Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Evaluation' (10.0.14393). Service Pack (0.0). SuiteMask = 400. Product Type = 18]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.125+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="util.cpp:2075">
<![LOG[Ccmsetup command line: "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install\ccmsetup.exe" ]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.125+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:3813">
<![LOG[Local Machine is joined to an AD domain]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.125+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:768">
<![LOG[Current AD forest name is autoscribe.com, domain name is autoscribe.com]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.250+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:896">
<![LOG[Domain joined client is in Intranet]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.250+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:1122">
<![LOG[DhcpGetOriginalSubnetMask entry point is supported.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.250+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmiputil.cpp:117">
<![LOG[Begin checking Alternate Network Configuration]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.250+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmiputil.cpp:1095">
<![LOG[Finished checking Alternate Network Configuration]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.250+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmiputil.cpp:1172">
<![LOG[Adapter {B8FE7238-D527-4919-A40A-50BB111B3575} is DHCP enabled. Checking quarantine status.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.250+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmiputil.cpp:436">
<![LOG[Adapter {B73BEA2F-3662-4CDB-AB5A-7C106DDD5BC5} is DHCP enabled. Checking quarantine status.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.250+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmiputil.cpp:436">
<![LOG[Current AD site of machine is SRV1]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.250+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:824">
<![LOG[Attempting to query AD for assigned site code]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.250+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:2133">
<![LOG[Performing AD query: '(&(ObjectCategory=MSSMSRoamingBoundaryRange)(|(&(MSSMSRangedIPLow<=3232261336)(MSSMSRangedIPHigh>=3232261336))(&(MSSMSRangedIPLow<=3232251010)(MSSMSRangedIPHigh>=3232251010))(&(MSSMSRangedIPLow<=3232238296)(MSSMSRangedIPHigh>=3232238296))(&(MSSMSRangedIPLow<=3232253561)(MSSMSRangedIPHigh>=3232253561))(&(MSSMSRangedIPLow<=2851995933)(MSSMSRangedIPHigh>=2851995933))))']LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:710">
<![LOG[Performing AD query: '(&(ObjectCategory=mSSMSSite)(|(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=192.168.100.0)(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=192.168.60.0)(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=192.168.10.0)(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=192.168.70.0)(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=169.254.0.0)(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=SRV1)))']LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:710">
<![LOG[Failed to get assigned site from AD. Error 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="2" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:260">
<![LOG[GetADInstallParams failed with 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="3" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:300">
<![LOG[SslState value: 224]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:4587">
<![LOG[Ccmsetup was run without any user parameters specified. Running without registering ccmsetup as a service.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:4652">
<![LOG[No sitecode is specified or detected. Assume AUTO sitecode.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:4656">
<![LOG[CCMHTTPPORT:    80]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:8730">
<![LOG[CCMHTTPSPORT:    443]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:8742">
<![LOG[CCMHTTPSSTATE:    224]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:8757">
<![LOG[CCMHTTPSCERTNAME:    ]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:8772">
<![LOG[FSP:    ]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:8813">
<![LOG[CCMFIRSTCERT:    1]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.281+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:8859">
<![LOG[No MP or source location has been explicitly specified.  Trying to discover a valid content location...]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:4907">
<![LOG[Looking for MPs from AD...]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:4915">
<![LOG[Current AD forest name is autoscribe.com, domain name is autoscribe.com]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:896">
<![LOG[Domain joined client is in Intranet]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:1122">
<![LOG[DHCP entry points already initialized.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmiputil.cpp:75">
<![LOG[Begin checking Alternate Network Configuration]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmiputil.cpp:1095">
<![LOG[Finished checking Alternate Network Configuration]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmiputil.cpp:1172">
<![LOG[Adapter {B8FE7238-D527-4919-A40A-50BB111B3575} is DHCP enabled. Checking quarantine status.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmiputil.cpp:436">
<![LOG[Adapter {B73BEA2F-3662-4CDB-AB5A-7C106DDD5BC5} is DHCP enabled. Checking quarantine status.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="ccmiputil.cpp:436">
<![LOG[Current AD forest name is autoscribe.com, domain name is autoscribe.com]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:896">
<![LOG[Domain joined client is in Intranet]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:1122">
<![LOG[Current AD site of machine is SRV1]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:824">
<![LOG[Attempting to query AD for assigned site code]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.297+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:2133">
<![LOG[Performing AD query: '(&(ObjectCategory=MSSMSRoamingBoundaryRange)(|(&(MSSMSRangedIPLow<=3232261336)(MSSMSRangedIPHigh>=3232261336))(&(MSSMSRangedIPLow<=3232251010)(MSSMSRangedIPHigh>=3232251010))(&(MSSMSRangedIPLow<=3232238296)(MSSMSRangedIPHigh>=3232238296))(&(MSSMSRangedIPLow<=3232253561)(MSSMSRangedIPHigh>=3232253561))(&(MSSMSRangedIPLow<=2851995933)(MSSMSRangedIPHigh>=2851995933))))']LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:710">
<![LOG[Performing AD query: '(&(ObjectCategory=mSSMSSite)(|(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=192.168.100.0)(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=192.168.60.0)(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=192.168.10.0)(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=192.168.70.0)(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=169.254.0.0)(mSSMSRoamingBoundaries=SRV1)))']LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="lsad.cpp:710">
<![LOG[Failed to get assigned site from AD. Error 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="2" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:260">
<![LOG[GetADInstallParams failed with 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="3" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:300">
<![LOG[Couldn't find an MP source through AD. Error 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:4932">
<![LOG[Current directory 'C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install' is not a valid source location.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:4969">
<![LOG[No valid source or MP locations]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="3" thread="7240" file="state.h:54">
<![LOG[Failed to get client version for sending state messages. Error 0x8004100e]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="2" thread="7240" file="state.cpp:164">
<![LOG[[] Params to send '5.0.8458.1007 Deployment "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install\ccmsetup.exe" ']LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="7240" file="state.cpp:209">
<![LOG[A Fallback Status Point has not been specified and no client was installed.  Message with STATEID='322' will not be sent.]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="state.cpp:240">
<![LOG[Failed to send status 322. Error (87D00215)]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="3" thread="7240" file="state.cpp:253">
<![LOG[Failed to connect to policy namespace. Error 0x8004100e]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="3" thread="7240" file="localpolicy.cpp:367">
<![LOG[Failed to revoke client upgrade local policy. Error 0x8004100e]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="3" thread="7240" file="localpolicy.cpp:394">
<![LOG[CcmSetup failed with error code 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="17:26:40.312+240" date="07-10-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="7240" file="ccmsetup.cpp:10711">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to run Configuration Manager Client if you are not using SCCM. You will not be able to do anything with it because CCM Client needs a SCCM server.